# ¿Es necesario importar md-autocomplete en Angular 1.5.8?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directivas

Este es mi primer proyecto en AngularJs y estoy intentando crear un filtro con el campo md-autocomplete pero no me aparece nada en mi página.

Al escribir la etiqueta  tampoco me aperece en sugerencias el paquete md- como si que me pasa con ng- u otros. Por eso me pregunto, ¿es necesario importarlo antes?

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                            <!--<input type="text" id="cliente" ng-model="cliente" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Cliente"
                                   ng-click="leftCursor()" ng-change="searchCliente()" /> -->
<md-content class="md-padding" ng-cloak>
<form>
    <md-autocomplete 
                 md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
                 md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
                 md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
                 md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
                 md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
                 md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
                 md-item-text="item.display"
                 md-min-length="0"
                 placeholder="US State?">
                 <md-item-template>
                 <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">
                 {{item.display}}
                 </span>
                 </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
</form>
</md-content>
```

Comment: Claro ! Si vas a usar cualquier extensión o librería adicional debes importarla para poder hacer uso de sus métodos, directivas...etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que importar la libreria Material Angular https://material.angularjs.org